# Правильно поставлены запятые в предложении?

Tags: запятая

Тонкие берёзы пожелтевшие,
тротуары засыпанные снегом...

Comment: @Веста, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Тонкие берёзы - пожелтевшие, тротуары - засыпанные снегом...

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Предложение  можно нормально прочесть  только при наличии пауз и  параллельной интонации. Это БСП, составные именные сказуемые в каждом простом предложении. Без тире грамматика будет неясной.

2) Сравнить: "Пожелтевшие тонкие березы, тротуары, засыпанные снегом ". Или: "Пожелтевшие тонкие березы,  засыпанные снегом тротуары ". Это назывные предложения.

3) Приведенный пример - это нечто среднее между этими вариантами, но с неправильным или незаконченным оформлением.

Comment: София, большое спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении: Листья на земле увядшие лежат. - Нужно выделять запятыми "увядшие"?

Comment: Здесь нет обособления, так как "увядшие" являются именной частью составного именного сказуемого. Но "увядшие лежат" - инверсия в сказуемом, что уместно только в стихотворной речи.

Comment: Листья на земле, увядшие, лежат.
Любое определение обособляется, если оно отделено от определяемого слова другими словами.Здесь сказуемое "лежат", а "увядшие" - определение.

Comment: Думаю, что в приведенном примере это именно инверсия без обособления. Инверсия связана с постановкой логического ударения на слово "увядшие", это смысловой центр высказывания (важно не то , что они лежат, а то, что они увяли).  При обособлении ударение падает на глагол "лежат", а что им (листьям) еще на земле делать? Поэтому не стоит применять правила чисто формально, без учета смысла.